# office-js the Excel will exited by using showHeaders

Tags: excel, office-js

The Excel will exited when I uncomment the `expensesTable.showHeaders = false` line.

[Excel exited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLGtD.png)

```
    Excel.run((context) => {
        const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem('Sample');
        const expensesTable = sheet.tables.add('A1:E1', true/*hasHeaders*/);
        // expensesTable.name = 'ExpensesTable';

        // expensesTable.getHeaderRowRange().values = [['Date', 'Merchant', 'Category', 'Amount', 'Amo12unt']];

        // expensesTable.showHeaders = false;

        expensesTable.rows.add(null, data.slice(0, 10));

        if (window.Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('ExcelApi', 1.2)) {
            sheet.getUsedRange()
                .format
                .autofitColumns();
            sheet.getUsedRange()
                .format
                .autofitRows();
        }

        sheet.activate();

        return context.sync();
    })
        .catch(console.log);
```

This problem started yesterday(2018/5/14).

`Excel version : Version 1806 (Build10205.20009)
Windiw version ：Microsoft Windows [版本 10.0.16299.431]`

But This problem does not appear in another PC.

Comment: Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can reproduce on build 1806 10212.20006. I have reported this as a probable bug here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/134

Answer (score 1):

I am Tong and I am an engineer at the Excel JavaScript API team. Thank your for letting us know the issue. We have already turn off the flight for the change that caused this issue. So if you restart your excel, the issue should be gone. I apologize for the inconvenience and trouble to you.